# Random variables and ordres of joint distributions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, bayes-theorem

I have a question on exchangeable random variables. I have always assumed that given random variables $X$ and $Y$ we have equality of the two joint distributions $p(X,Y)=p(Y,X)$ (don't we need this how we get the Bayes' theorem), but learning the definition of exchangeable random variables, I realized this is only possible if $X$ and $Y$ are exchangeable.

But then, how do we get the Bayes' theorem in the general case? Don't we define $p(Y|X)=p(Y,X)/p(X)$ and $p(X|Y)=p(X,Y)/p(Y)$?

**Edit:** I can understand the case where we interpret $(X,Y)$ as events or sets $(X=x,Y=y)$ as the answers below say. But I still have confusion over the general case. Namely, where we have the joint distribution $P_{X,Y}(dx,dy)=P^x_Y(dy)P_X(dx)$ where $P^x_Y$ is the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$. Now then when we apply Bayes, don't we need get $P_{X,Y}(dx,dy)=P_{Y,X}(dy,dx)$ since we should have $P_{Y,X}(dy,dx)=P_X^y(dx)P_Y(dy)$ by exchanging $X,Y$ above and $P_Y^x(dy)P_X(dx)=P_X^y(dx)P_Y(dy)$ is Bayes' theorem? So what goes wrong in the case of general joint distributions and not equivalences of set probabilities? This product rule of the joint distribution is from the general case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem.

And in the case of continuous random variables, why is the numerator for $f_{X|Y=y}(x,y)$ and $f_{Y|X=x}(x,y)$ both $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, the joint density of $(X,Y)$? Shouldn't the second be $f_{Y,X}(y,x)$, the joint density of $(Y,X)$? I can't see why $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y,X}(y,x)$
since this is not a set intersection but one is derived from differentiating the joint distribution function of $(X,Y)$ $F_{X,Y}$
and the other from $(Y,X)$ $F_{Y,X}$. So my question mainly is why are we able to ignore the order of the random variables when we consider the joint distributions, densities when they are not exchangeable.

Comment: Please, clarify the definition of $P(X, Y)$. Is it $P(X \cap Y)$?

Comment: @DaigakunoBaku It is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Then, of course, the statement $P(X, Y)=P(Y, X)$ is not true in general. Let $X$ have uniform distribution on $[0, 1]$, $Y$ have uniform distribution on $[2, 3]$, and $X, Y$ be independent. Then, given a pair of values $x\in [0, 1], y \in [2, 3]$, $P(y, x)$ is not even defined, if by "joint distribution" you mean the probability density function of the joint distribution. If you mean, literally, the joint distribution, then, again, $P(X, Y)$ and $P(Y, X)$ are completely different, since one is defined on the Borel algebra of $[0, 1]\times [2, 3]$, while the other on $B([2, 3]\times [0, 1])$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think is more of a notational confusion rather than conceptual. When we write $P(A, B)$, we usually mean, event $A$ and event $B$ happens, so in this sense $P(A, B) = P(B, A) = P(A\cap B)$. Note that $P$ is not a function here, just a convention to talk about probabilities of events.

On the other hand, if we are talking about functions, the meaning is completely different. In this case $P(A, B)$ means the first variable is $A$ and the second variable is $B$. In math, you can consider symmetric functions to better understand exchangability. For example, $f(x,y) = x^2 + y^2$ is symmetric so $f(x,y) = f(y,x)$, i.e. you can swap the first and second variables. But this is not true in general, of course. Exchangeability is a similar idea in probability theory.

**Update:** I think I better understand where you got confused (and I must admit that it's more subtle than it looks). I will use the notation you used to clarify things.

First of all, suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same set $[0,1]$ so that the support of the joint distribution wouldn't complicate the discussion.

What you are saying is this
$$f_{X,Y}(X=a, Y=b) = f_{Y,X}(Y=b, X=a)$$
which is always true. Because this identity follows from a simple change of variables (coordinates): you are expressing the joint density in the $X$-$Y$ plane on the LHS and in the $Y$-$X$ plane on the RHS. Therefore, $f_{X,Y}(X=a, Y=b)$ and  $f_{Y,X}(Y=b, X=a)$ live in different coordinate systems, and of course, the joint density when $X=a$ and $Y=b$ should be the same regardless of the coordinate system so they are equal.

However, the exchangeability concept is different. Its definition with this notation, would be something like this
$$f_{X,Y}(X=a, Y=b) = f_{X,Y}(X=b, Y=a), \quad \forall a,b\in [0,1]\times [0,1]$$
So we require the joint density function to be symmetric with respect to the $y=x$ line in the *same* $X$-$Y$ plane system.

If you want a concrete example, take $f_{X,Y}(X=a, Y=b)= 6ab^2$. Then of course, $f_{Y,X}(Y=b, X=a) = 6ab^2$ but
$$f_{X,Y}(X=a, Y=b) = 6ab^2 \neq 6ba^2 = f_{X,Y}(X=b, Y=a), \quad \forall a,b\in [0,1]\times [0,1]$$
so $X$ and $Y$ are not exchangeable.

On the other hand, the bivariate Gaussian distribution is exchangeable. For simplicity look at the standard bivariate
$$ f_{X,Y}(X=a, Y=b) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\text{exp}[-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} (a^2 - 2ab\rho + b^2 ) ] $$
$$ f_{X,Y}(X=b, Y=a) = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1-\rho^2}}\text{exp}[-\frac{1}{2(1-\rho^2)} (b^2 - 2ba\rho + a^2 ) ] $$
$$ \implies f_{X,Y}(X=a, Y=b) = f_{X,Y}(X=b, Y=a)  $$

**Update 2** re-your question:
When you express the joint distribution you decide which variable goes to x-axis and which to y-axis so you choose to work either in (X,Y) or (Y,X) coordinate system and in that sense, the chosen coordinate system induces an order between X and Y (i.e. which one is first variable). On the other hand, the expressions $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ and $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$ don't involve any order- there is no "first" or "second" variable in these expressions. So if you were thinking "$f_{X|Y=y}(x)$ is computed from $f_{X,Y}(X,Y)$ so $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ should be computed from $f_{Y,X}(Y,X)$", that is not true because there is no order implied in conditional densities. But in principle, you could compute $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ using $f_{Y,X}(Y,X)$ but then you would be working in two coordinate systems, which is not practical. For example, when you compute both of the marginal densities from the same $f(X,Y)$, we have a nice geometric illustration for independence: at any point $(a,b)$, the joint density is the product of two marginal densities that intersect at the right angle but if you compute the marginals from different coordinate systems they will live in two different planes! In general, if you carry around two coordinate systems in your analysis, it would be ambiguous which variable is $X$ which is $Y$ in an expression like $f(a,b)$ so you would have to write $f(X=a,Y=b)$, $f(Y=a,X=b)$ each time or use a different function, say $g$, for $Y$-$X$ coordinate system so that when you write $g(a,b)$, it would be clear that $Y=a$ and $X=b$. Alternatively, as you did initially, the subscripts of $f$ in $f_{X,Y}(X,Y)$ $f_{Y,X}(Y,X)$ differentiate which coordinate system we are working in so they are not both $f$. But again, there is no reason to let all this confusion in. Simply we stick to the same coordinate system.

Comment: I have tried to elaborate my question in the edited post please take a look thank you.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. I think it will clarify the confusion.

Comment: Then what is the justification for having $f_{X,Y}$, the joint density for $(X,Y)$ as the numerator for both the conditional densities $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ and $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$?

Comment: I have just posted an update to address your question, hope it helps.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you could compute $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ using $f(Y,X)$ but then you would be working in two coordinate systems? And actually what exactly is $f$ here? Don't we usually mean $f$ is $f_{X,Y}$ with $X,Y$ suppressed? So $f$ is the joint density of $(X,Y)$, but then this is ordered isn't it? I'm not clear why the conditional densities don't involve any order.

Comment: Yes, I agree that using the same $f$ for the joint distribution when working in Y-X coordinate system as I explained in my previous comment. The conditional distribution doesn't involve any order, $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ simply gives the probability that Y=y when X=x (assume discrete case) so there is no order between them and you can compute it using different coordinate systems.

Comment: Okay so we are just abusing notation here with the same $f$ because we mean intersection of events just as in the discrete case. Could you give me any reference on the geometric interpretation?

Comment: Not really. In order not to abuse notation when we say $f$ is a joint pdf, it is either in X-Y coordinate system or Y-X coordinate system so if we write $f(X,Y)$, X always the first variable and Y the second. Note that you didn't initially write just $f$ but $f_{X,Y}$ and $f_{Y,X}$ so this is another way of differentiating two coordinate systems. But as I explained before you won't find anywhere where people use $f_{X,Y}$ and $f_{Y,X}$ together for no good reason. For the geometric interpretation: the idea is the same as partial derivatives.

Comment: Take $z=f(x,y)$. Consider $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)$. To picture this, we consider a slice of the graph of $z$ at $y=y_0$ and look at the slope of the tangent line at $x_0$. So this slice is parallel to x-axis. For $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)$ we take a similar slice at $x=x_0$, which is paralell to y-axis.

Comment: Ok that part is clear to me now. My only confusion is with the statement that it isn't true that $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ should be computed from $f(Y,X)$. Since by definition $f_{X|Y=y}(x)$ is computed from $f(X,Y)$, shouldn't by symmetry $f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ should be computed from $f(Y,X)$? I can't see why we can compute it using different coordinate systems because then $f_{X,Y}$ and $f_{Y,X}$ should be interchangeable but then the values $f_{X,Y}$ and $f_{Y,X}$ can be different.

Comment: See my Update 2 above, please. I edited it a little bit to address this better.

Comment: My question is regarding the last sentence you make. Why can we stick to the same coordinate system, which I understand to be taken as $(X,Y)$ coordinate. Taking $(Y,X)$ instead could lead to a different value when we compute conditional densities. So you say that there is no order involved in conditional densities but by fixing the coordinate system to $(X,Y)$ aren't we essentially imposing an order? What justifies this particular coordinate and not the other one?

Answer (score 1):

First, the statement $P(X, Y)=P(Y, X)$, where $X, Y$ are random variables and $P(X, Y)$ is their joint distribution, is not true. $P(X, Y)$ is a probability measure defined on $\sigma(X) \times \sigma(Y)$, where $\sigma(X), \sigma(Y)$ are the sigma-algebras of measurable sets on $X$ and $Y$ respectively. $\sigma(X) \times \sigma(Y)$ and $\sigma(Y) \times \sigma(X)$ are different sets. Example: define two discrete distributions, $X$ at $\{0, 1\}$, $Y$ at $\{0, 1, 2\}$. The joint distribution $P(X, Y)$ is then defined at $\{0, 1\} \times \{0, 1, 2\}$, while $P(Y, X)$ is defined at $\{0, 1, 2\}\times \{0, 1\}$. Even if $X$ and $Y$ are defined on the same set, their joint distribution does not have to be symmetric with respect to swapping of the arguments. Moreover, the symmetry of joint distribution is not required even for a pair of independent random variables on the same set: consider independent $X$ on $\{0, 1\}$ that is $1$ with probability 1, and $Y$ on $\{1, 0\}$ that is $0$ with probability 1. Then the joint distribution is described by the $2\times 2$ matrix $\pmatrix{0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0}$, which is obviously not symmetric with respect to transposition.

Second, the Bayes theorem uses the symmetry of set intersection, not the symmetry of joint distribution, and its statement is about probabilities of events. Given *events* $A, B$, $P(A|B)= \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$. The theorem is proved by noting that, since $P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}$
$$P(A|B)P(B) = \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)} P(B) = P(A \cap B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}P(A) = P(B|A)P(A)$$

You can apply the theorem to the joint distribution $P(X, Y)$ to get
$$P(X=x|Y=y)=\frac{P(Y=y|X=x)P(X=x)}{P(Y=y)}$$
$$P(Y=y|X=x)=\frac{P(X, Y)[X=x \cap Y=y]}{P(X)[X=x]}$$
where $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ are the marginal distributions, obtained by integrating $P(X, Y)$ with one fixed argument.

Comment: This clears up for the discrete case. But still a bit of confusion for me in the general case where we have the joint distribution $P_{X,Y}(dx,dy)=P_Y^x(dy)P_X(dx)$ where $P_Y^x$ is the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$. Now then when we apply Bayes, don't we need to use $P_{X,Y}(dx,dy)=P_{Y,X}(dy,dx)$? This product rule of the joint distribution is from the general case of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes%27_theorem.

Comment: And in the case of continuous random variables, why is the denominator for $f_{X|Y=y}(x,y)$ and $f_{Y|X=x}$ both $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$, the joint density of $X$ and $Y$? Shouldn't the second be $f_{Y,X}(y,x)$? I can't see why $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{Y,X}(y,x)$ since this is not a set intersection and one is derived from differentiating $F_{X,Y}$ and the other from $F_{Y,X}$?

Comment: I have tried to elaborate my question in the edited post please take a look thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I now see where I misunderstood things and the correct way to think about this. So first in the two dimensional case, say we have the random vector $(X_1, X_2)$. Then this is specifically ordered by the indices. So when we have the pdf $f_{1,2}(x,y)$, where I suppressed $X$ in the subscript of $f$ for convenience, $x$ corresponds to the value for the first coordinate $X_1$ and $y$ for the second coordinate $X_2$.

Because of this we have $f_{X_2|X_1=x}(y)=f_{1,2}(x,y)/f_1(x)$ and not $f_{X_2|X_1=x}(y)=f_{2,1}(x,y)/f_1(x)$ because by conditioning on $X_1=x$ we must have $X_2=y$ and the probability density that gives this is precisely $f_{1,2}(x,y)$. $f_{2,1}(x,y)$ means that $X_2=x$ and $X_1=y$, which contradicts the conditioning. So in essence, the order is predetermined when we consider the random vector $(X_1,X_2)$.

Therefore, we can generalize this to $n$-dimensional case. For convenience in the $3$-dimensional case, if we are given $(X_1,X_2,X_3)$, then we can decompose the joint density in any order, i.e., $f_{1,2,3}(x,y,z)=f_1(x)f_{2|1=x}(y)f_{3,1=x,2=y}(z)$, but also we can permute $X_1,X_2,X_3$ in the decomposition in any order such as $f_2(y)f_{3|2=y}(z)f_{1|2=y,3=z}(x)$ because the order is fixed and $x$ corresponds to the first cooordinate value of $X_1$, $y$ to $X_2$, $z$ to $X_3$ and the joint density for this is represented by $f_{1,2,3}(x,y,z)$.